# how to run Solr in Cloud mode

Tags: ubuntu, service, solr, cloud, bin

I have installed Solr 8.5.4 in Ubuntu. How to run it in Cloud mode?
I have found that in order to run in Cloud mode, I should use the following command:

```
bin/solar start
```

but there is no folder called bin!!
I also tried the following command but not work:

```
service solr start
```

Comment: If you've installed the systemd configuration files, it would be `service solr start`, not `solr service start`. Also to run in cloud mode when you're using systemd, you usually want to set the `ZK_HOST` variable to configure your zookeeper ensemble. See Taking Solr to Production for more detailed information: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/taking-solr-to-production.html

Comment: u are right, it is "service solr start".
could u please explain more specific what I need to do?
I have followed the mentioned link but I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It's impossible to say without you providing some more context about what your issue is. Edit your question with any error messages, with the output form `journalctl -xe` and other tools.

Answer (score 0):

To run solr in cloud mode it's very simple just use -c flag.

```
➜  solr-9.2.1  bin/solr start -c -f
```

here,
-c -> cloud
-f -> to start solr in forground

Comment: check this https://solr.apache.org/downloads.html out for downloading sorce or binary files.